# Does changing a copy of a variable change the original?

Tags: c#, oop, entity-framework-4.1

I had an **access to modified closure** error in the code below

```
foreach (var user in Entities.User)
            {
                bool any = Entities.Person.Any(
                    p => p.Name == user.Name);
            }
```

So I changed it to

```
foreach (var user in Entities.User)
            {
User theUser = user;
                bool any = Entities.Person.Any(
                    p => p.Name == theUser.Name);
            }
```

Now, the question is that I want to be able to modify a property of the user object.  Does it matter if I do either of the following.  Will they both save down to the database when I call `SaveChanges` on the DbContext?

```
user.Property = 1;
```

or

```
theUser.Property = 1;
```

Comment: You should run a similar test in code to verify the answers below.  Get used to seeing what is a reference to an object vs. an object itself.

Comment: Given that `Any` executes immediately (i.e. is not deferred), there's no need to capture a locally scoped variable. You can safely ignore the warning (although for sanity, it's probably better to make it go away).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. `User` in this case is most likely a referencec type and thus variables of that type are just references pointing to an instance. The assignment just changes another variable to point to the same instance.

Answer (score 2):

Those are reference types. So both of those variables point to the same object. `Property` will be changed in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

User is a class, so you aren't actually copying the user, you're just copying a reference (or a pointer, as it's sometimes called) to that user.  Both copies of that references will "see" any changes to the underlying object.